# Как модернизировать программу, чтобы при вводе возрастающей последовательности она правильно работала?

Tags: java

```
package chapterfirst;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HighestLowest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Введите цифры через запятую и нажмите <Enter>");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sequenseRandom = keyboard.next();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sequenseRandom);
        int start = 0;
        int result;
        int highest = 0;
        int lowest = 2000000000;
        while (matcher.find(start))
        {
            String value = sequenseRandom.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
            result = Integer.parseInt(value);
            start = matcher.end();
            if (result >= highest)
            {
                highest = result;
            }
            else
            {
                if (result <= lowest)
                {
                    lowest = result;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Максимум: " + highest);
        System.out.println("Минимум: " + lowest);
        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Модернизировать? Очень просто. Пофиксьте баги и перейдите на Streams.

Comment: Проще всего обновление минимума из под `else` унести и каждый раз делать. Либо отдельно обработать первый член последовательности и инициализировать оба поля им.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из вашего кода не сильно понятно чего вы добиваетесь. Вот пример программы, которая находит минимальное и максимальное значение из введенной последовательности положительных целых чисел.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean exit = false;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while ( !exit ) {
        System.out.println("Введите цифры через запятую и нажмите <Enter>:");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();

        // проверка допустимых значений
        if ( input == null || input.trim().isEmpty() || !input.matches("^[\\d]+[\\d,]+$") ) {
            System.out.println("Введенная последовательность содержит недопустимые символы");
            continue;
        }

        // извлекаем последовательность чисел
        String[] values = input.split(",");
        int[] sequence = new int[values.length];
        for ( int i = 0; i < values.length; i++ ) {
            try {
                sequence[i] = Integer.parseInt(values[i]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                continue;
            }
        }

        // сортируем
        Arrays.sort(sequence);

        System.out.println("Минимум:" + sequence[0]);
        System.out.println("Максимум:" + sequence[sequence.length - 1]);
    }

    scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: Массивы я ещё не знаю, делаю по учебнику........

Comment: !input.matches("^[\\d]+[\\d,]+$")           что это значит?

Comment: @Петя Петросян Регулярное выражение, которое проверяет, что строка (input) содержит только цифры и запятые и при этом начинается с цифры.